# Install another PHP version. Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, configuration, php

How can I install another PHP version?

I have php 5.4.5 for now, but I need the version 5.3.15 running too.

How can I perform this on Fedora 17? Without using a Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the standard ways of doing this is to download the php source code from http://php.net/downloads.php and compile it with `./configure --prefix=/opt/php/5.3.15` or something to that effect. Then, your new php will not conflict with any system packages. Note that on Fedora, you will need to install a bunch of -devel packages to build php with the functionality you most likely want.

Comment: I've done this. But, where is the final php executable? Looks hidden o.O

Comment: @GarouDan I would guess /opt/php/5.3.15/bin

Comment: You will also need to run `make` and `make install` (not sure if you did that already). But jordanm's answer is where it should be.

Comment: I'had seen on another question that I couldn't do the make install, but this is wrong. It works. Thanks.